# Declaration file for class-module (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I use a node module that's not found by typings and doesn't exist in definelytyped.

the basic use of the module is:

```
import * as SomeClass from 'some-module';

var someObject = new SomeClass("some string");
someObject.someMethod();
```

As you can see, this module exports a class as its default. I haven't figured out how to write the declaration file for it.

This is the best I managed to do:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
    export default class SomeClass {
        constructor (someArg: string);
        someMethod(): void;
    }
}
```

BTW it does work JavaScriptly. It's only the TypeScript bothers me.

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Are you transpiling your code down to es5? If you do, then I would recommend you to use `import SomeClass = require('some-module')` instead....it's a long story short

Answer (score 3):

For the declaration, you need to do this:

```
declare module 'some-module' {
    class SomeClass {
        constructor (someArg: string);
        someMethod(): void;
    }
    namespace SomeClass {}
    export = SomeClass;
}
```

UPDATE: Thank you to Blake Embrey for pointing out, the hack `namespace SomeClass {}` is needed to get this working.
see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5073 for more detail.

Comment: It produces an error: 'TS2497: Module '"some-module"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.' on the import statement. I transpile to ES6 BTW.

Comment: You need to put it in a separate file. Not in a file with top-level import/export.
Save it as `custom-typings/some-module.d.ts` and include it in your tsconfig.json.

Comment: Is it an application or a package?

Comment: shoot, seems like something changed in 2.2 and this does not work anymore. Need to figure out what's the alternative myself.

Comment: It's in a separate file. I've created some declaration files already. I know how to do that. It's just a special case because it has a default export which is a class.

Comment: Do you wanna say that it's a known bug?

Comment: Don't want to say it is a bug yet. Just need more time to investigate. IMO it is actually good to break this interop. It is a can of worms.

Comment: Just want to ping back that I haven't got a chance looking into it. But I do see it is working fine for my other projects, so it must be some setting issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid TypeScript error and do not worry about ItelliSense just declare your class library like that in the begining of you file for example:

```
declare var SomeClass: any;
```